# Pass a member function to create a free function boost pointer

Tags: c++, boost, function-pointers

I try to get this code running. I am almost there but I got stuck with the line:

```
 _f = std::bind1st(
         std::mem_fun(f, x);
```

First of all please understand that I **don't want to change any code, but the constructor**. Why? Because I want to learn. Eventually I want to write a wrapper class `Func`, that can handle free functions and member function at the same time, in this very manner.

So what wuld I have to put as the first argument inside the `std::mem_func()`-call???
I tried numerous things.

Probably this is a duplicate, but I don't know how to search for this problem. I lack the vocabulary. If someone can point to a tutorial or something, that would help me to express this problem, I would also appreciate it.

Here is the full sample code:

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    int foo(int i)
    {
        return i;
    };
};

class Func
{

public:

   Func(X *x,  int (X::* f) (int))
   {
      _f = std::bind1st(
         std::mem_fun(f, x);

      std::cout << _f(5); // Call x.foo(5)
   };

private:

    boost::function<int (int)> _f;
};

int main()
{

    X x;

    Func func(&x, &X::foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are learning - have a look at `boost::bind` - things will click...

Comment: This example comes from the boost function documentation. There they don't make use of boost:bind in this context. If you could change the line I had trouble with into a (simple) boost::bind()-call, I'd be happy to know about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you just forgot a paren:

```
_f = std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(f), x);
```

Although I would initialize with

```
Func(X *x,  int (X::* f) (int))
  : _f(std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(f), x))
{
    std::cout << _f(5); // Call x.foo(5)
};
```

(It doesn't matter in this case, but this style is safer in the long run.)

Comment: Thanks, that's it. How could I not get that right...maybe I should take a break. ;-) I can only mark your answer as correct in 3 minutes. Be sure I will.

Comment: @AudioDroid: I can't blame you. GCC's first error is `no matching function for call to ‘mem_fun(int (X::*&)(int), X*&)’` rather than a plain syntax error for a missing paren.

Comment: I just extended this example to a function (e.g. sum()) with two int's as arguments, and in short...it is all not working any more. :-( I will try a little longer then maybe open another question.

Answer (score 1):

I would refactor the class slightly to use `boost::function` in the interface, and then the user can decide how to bind in the most generic way:

```
struct X {
    int foo(int i) { return i; };
};
class Func {
    boost::function<int (int)> _f;
public:
   Func( boost::function<int (int)> f ){
      _f = f;
      std::cout << _f(5);
   };
};
int foo( int x ) { return 2*x; }
int bar( int x, int multiplier ) { return x*multiplier; }
int main() {
    X x;
    Func func1( boost::bind( &X::foo, &x, _1 ) ); // this does the magic
    Func func2( boost::bind( &foo, _1 ) );        // you can also bind free functions...
    Func func3( boost::bind( &bar, _1, 5 ) );     // or with different arguments
}
```

Comment: That is also a nice idea, however I would like to keep all the "boost stuff" hidden. Thanks for seeing into this though.